# Set type of a variable dynamically in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make a generic model in which some fields are fixed and only one field changes, so the model is

```
class APIResponse(
    var msg: String? = null,
    var code: String? = null,
    var data: Any? = null  // dynamic field
)
```

I want to set `data` variable of this `APIResponse` class to other different types on the go with the help of a function:

```
fun generateApiResponseAdapter(type: Any): APIResponse {
    return APIResponse(null, null, type)
}
```

so for example if I have a model as:

```
class Transactions(
    val id: Int,
    val amount: Float,
    val category: String,
    val regarding: String,
){
    companion object
}
```

I can get APIResponse as:

```
val resp = generateApiResponseAdapter(Transactions)
```

and then access `Transactions` fields through `data` variable of `resp` like:

```
resp.data.amount
```

<If my method is not correct, please suggest how can I do that>

I'm new at kotlin so the question might be dumb ;_;

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to create a single response model for all the different possible responses that your api returns?

Comment: Yes, whenever I have to pass class into Gson builder, I just want to pass APIResponse class as my API response is already formatted, the data attribute in API response will be assigned to data attribute in APIResponse class, I want that data attribute in APIResponse class to be dynamically set

Comment: So do you need to only "cast" the existing data structure, as in your example or actually choose the type for the data deserialization, as in your comment? These are much different cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hint is in the first sentence in your question: you need to use generics. Start by making your `APIResponse` generic:

```kotlin
class APIResponse<T : Any>(
    var msg: String? = null,
    var code: String? = null,
    var data: T? = null
)
```

Then the type of the data is included in the type of the `APIResponse` itself, for example:

```kotlin
val resp = APIResponse(data = transactions) // type of `resp` is `APIResponse<Transactions>`
```

When we deserialize the data using Gson we have to provide the information on what is the type of the data. Standard way is to use its [TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) utility, although in Kotlin I suggest to create our own, very simple extension:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val json = "{\"msg\":\"sample-msg\",\"code\":\"sample-code\",\"data\":{\"id\":1,\"amount\":1.0,\"category\":\"sample-category\",\"regarding\":\"sample-regarding\"}}"
    val resp = Gson().fromJson<APIResponse<Transactions>>(json)

    println(resp) // make both classes data classes to see meaningful output here
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified R> Gson.fromJson(json: String): R = fromJson(json, typeOf<R>().javaType)
```

You can read more about the generics in Kotlin in the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html